# Xpages Bootstrap setup error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I am new to xpages and to bootstrap also.

I have a query [Sample code URL](http://www.schmhen.de/2012/08/30/xpages-create-a-responsive-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap-2/). I am trying to use the sample code in my xpage but I get the below error:

> Cannot find the library org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.library, required by the application /Pranesh/Tracking.nsf.

I have setup the bootstrap files in Designer. Also done the same on Dom server in Plugin and features file as mentioned in the Ext Lib Installation guide.

Comment: you should post your codes here (edit your question).

Comment: Did you install Bootstrap4XPages as a plugin on the server using an Update Site db?

Comment: Are you also testing against the server that you added the plugin to, or are you using Designer's "Preview" feature?

Answer (score 6):

The error message indicates that the [Bootstrap4XPages](http://bootstrap4xpages.openntf.org) library isn't installed on the server (assuming you're accessing the application on the server).

Best practice to install plugins like this is, just as Per mentioned, through a so called **update site** database. That process is described [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_USING_AN_NSF_BASED_UPDATE_SITE_OVER.html). Basically it involves the following steps:

- create an update site database on your server (from the Eclipse Update Site template)
- add the update site to your `notes.ini` file:

  OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES=updatesite.nsf
- (if you've changed the notes.ini: restart the server)
- import the plugin to the update site database and restart the HTTP task

Don't forget to restart the HTTP task after you've installed the library. To check if it was succesfully installed you can issue the following command in the server console:

```
tell http osgi ss org.openntf
```

This command will show you the installed plugins from the `org.openntf` package. It should list the Bootstrap plugin as `org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap_<version>`.

Comment: Hi Mark, I am having a similar issue. I have setup updatesite-runtime.nsf in the root of my server (downloaded from openntf.org, and signed by me). the ID signing the update site is the admin ID. I have setup a configruration setting Notes.INI setting with OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES=updatesite-runtime.nsf. I have restarted the server, and restarted the http task, but I do not get the line "NSF Based plugins are being installed in the OSGi runtime. For more information please consult the log". Any ideas?

Comment: Did you also sign the plugins? That's a required step for plugins that were added to the updatesite by someone else. You can do that by opening the updatesite database in the Notes client and click `Actions -> Sign All Content`

Comment: Mark, I could kiss you! That was it. Dank je veel!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Bootstrap with a local webserver.:

1. Download the latest extension library from here: [OpenNTF](http://extlib.openntf.org)
2. Follow the instructions to install it in your Domino Desginer.
3. Copy the **plugins** and the **features** directories from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\Data\workspace\applications\eclipse

to

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\IBM\Notes\Data\domino\workspace\applications\eclipse

Bootstrap will work as a charm.